# Anything wrong with overwritting class instance methods?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

Is it bad practice to overwrite ES6 class instance methods?

Let's say I have a class `Person`, all instances of class Person will have a `wakeUp` method that defaults to calling a `washFace()` and `eatBreakfast()` function. This is the fallback behavior desired for all instances of Person, however some instances might have a different `wakeUp` routine, for those ones I override the default `wakeUp` method:

```
class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  wakeUp() {
    washFace()
    eatBreakfast()
  }

}

const user1 = new Person('Jon Doe');
const user2 = new Person('Jane Doe');

user1.wakeUp = () => {
    washFace()
    drinkCoffee()
}

user2.wakeUp = () => {
    washFace()
    drinkTea()
}
```

This works as expected, however it is not something that I see in use very often so I'm just wondering if it's a bad practice/why?

EDIT: example above is just a simplification, this is for a CRUD hook library, some instances have their own behavior for the CRUD hooks that is not shared with any other instance and only applies to that one in particular, ex. onDelete of this particular instance call foo, furthermore all of the instances are created and documented in the codebase

Comment: are your users really this individually or maybe u want subclasses?

Comment: It’s indicative of weird design. Do you have a real-world example?

Comment: "*This works as expected*" - no it doesn't. You need to use `this.` to call methods, and you must not use arrow functions as methods.

Comment: I think it would be the best to define each behavior, maybe this will help you: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-subclassing/

Comment: It isn't _wrong_ to override methods - its just wrong to do it like this. This is a design question and therefore will only bring opinions.

Comment: No, this is not a bad practice, it's rather common. However: 1) the term one would use for this is "handler", "hook" or "callback", not "method" (which are "overridden" in a subclass, not "overwritten") 2) The default implementation would usually be initialised in the constructor, not inherited from the prototype 3) the property might not be overwritten from outside, as if the class knew nothing about it, but a) using `setWakeup(cb)`, b) passed to the constructor or c) at least be documented

Comment: Notice that in this particular instance, the sequence of `wakeUp` is the same for each person. You'd rather overwrite what `eatBreakfast()` does not the whole `wakeUp` method.

Comment: @Bergi - it might be a common practice to override object properties, but it is a terrible practice to change the behavior of a class method (it _is_ a method on the class), creates code that is difficult to follow and diagnose and reeks of lack of software design.

Comment: @RandyCasburn That's what I'm saying, it's all about the design of the `Person` class. Is  `wakeUp` a method or a callback property? Is it documented as a hook, and what invariants does it have?

Comment: "*all of the instances are created and documented in the codebase*" - I was talking about the documentation of the `Person` class, stating explicitly that `wakeUp` can be overwritten to hook into it, not that the behaviour of the individual instances is documented.

Comment: `example above is just a simplification`, we can't answer that question because there are so many design patterns for each usecase

Answer (score 2):

The example you gave is very contrived, so the answer to this will depend a bit on the real world situation.

It can be useful in *some* circumstances to override the method of a specific object. This is often done during unittesting for example.

I think it's more common to see this done with subclassing & polymorphism.

However, in the real world I think there's not that many uses for subclasses and polymorphism (with many notable exceptions), and often things are better done imperatively or functionally.

So there's no one true answer here imho.

Comment: _So there's no one true answer here imho._ & this is why the question should be closed as opinion based - such as "_in the real world I think..._"  :-)